# Selecting Unmatched records From two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need a Mysql query for my following problem.

I have two tables.

1. **Exam** with fields **id** and **examname**
2. **Exam_Applied** with fields **id** , **examname** and **student_id**

Here **student_id** is the id of student who applied the exam and I am storing in **Exam_Applied**

Now I need a query to **Select the examname From Table Exam which are not applied by the particular student_id**

help me plz.

Comment: This sounds like a hw question. Indeed, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN` to answer your question. Basically what it does is inside subquery, it ***gets all the `examname` taken by the specific student***. The `NOT IN` checks the examName of table `Exam` which are not present on table `Exam_Applied`

```
SELECT  id, examName
FROM    Exam
WHERE   examName NOT IN
        (
            SELECT examName
            FROM Exam_Applied
            WHERE Student_ID = 'idHERE'
        )
```

Hope this makes sense

[image]

Comment: Assuming `id` refers to the exam's id in both tables I'd join on it and since the field names are identical I'd replace `ON` with `USING(id)`

Comment: @Ariel you have the point. but i'm not really sure if `ID` on `Exam_Applied` is a foreign key from `Exam` table. I think it serves as the primary key of `Exam_Applied` table.

Comment: Hai its done...Thanks a lot @John Woo...Thanks a lot For your Help

Comment: @JohnWoo Sorry for off topic, do you ever sleep?

Comment: @JohnWoo Seems like you're on 24/7 ;)